# Byte Buddy Adding Try blocks to existing methods

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy, javaagents

Using Byte Buddy, I'm trying to add a few on `@Advice.OnMethodExit` and `@Advice.OnMethodEnter`. I would like to add blocks like this by the custom agent I'm building.

```
public String getSomeMethodName() {
        try{

// Default block of code present without instrumentation

        }finally {
// Some Code Snippets added by agent.
        }
    }
```

Basically the function does not even have `try` block. How can I add that as well as the `finally` block. Is it a good practice to do so? Or what is the best practice to achieve this?

What am trying is adding

```
try{ 

 }catch(){
 }
```

in `OnMethod.Enter`.

Would like to include `finally` block `OnMethod.Exit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Advice.OnMethodExit(onThrowable = Throwable.class)`. This triggers the advice even if any throwable type was thrown what is the semantics of a finally block.

Comment: Does it include the block of `try` and `finally` ?

Comment: Basically am trying to include `jaeger` tracing spans opened on `OnMethodEnter` I want to close them using `finally` in `OnMethodExit` ?

Comment: As said, finally blocks are basically identical to catch(Throwable) blocks with a rethrowing instructions. Byte Buddy models them in a single concept.